# hide empty attributes from product page attributes tab

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

i have this code to hide product attributes which has no value (empty attributes) from frontend:

```
<?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
```

i have copied this to my groupview.phtml (my alternative attributes file) like this:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
    <div class="attributesgroups-title">
        <h3 style="margin:0; color:white;"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        </div>
        <table style="border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;" class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
            <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/attributes/'.$_data['code'].'.png')?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>" /><span class="separator">|</span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

but i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /attributes.phtml on line 24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement isn't closed:

```
if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
```

You need a closing `}` before the `endforeach`.